# Pandas Specify time range in DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, timestamp

I´m struggling with the different pandas index formats.

My univariate time series (data) looks like this

```
2015-01-01 22:00:01.973    1.210525
2015-01-01 22:00:03.297    1.210490
2015-01-01 22:00:23.922    1.210485
2015-01-01 22:00:24.507    1.210480
2015-01-01 22:01:05.979    1.210490
2015-01-01 22:01:08.390    1.210525
2015-01-01 22:01:09.899    1.210520
2015-01-01 22:01:09.950    1.210505
2015-01-01 22:01:13.576    1.210505
2015-01-01 22:01:19.984    1.210485
2015-01-01 22:01:27.936    1.210510
```

where

```
>>> type(data)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> type(data.index)
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
>>>
```

I have a function that extracts a starting point and an endpoint, say

```
>>>start
textdate
2015-01-01 22:00:03.297    1.210490
Name: mean, dtype: float64
>>>

>>>end
textdate
2015-01-01 22:01:19.984    1.210485
Name: mean, dtype: float64
>>>
```

How can I slice the series from start to end based on the index values which seem to be of DatetimeIndex format themselves as

```
>>> start.index
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01 22:00:03.297'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'textdate', freq=None)
>>>
```

I tried this

```
series = data[start.index : end.index]
```

which gives me

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input to Timestamp
```

But I failed to convert the DatetimeIndex objects start and end into Timestamps...

Comment: does `data.loc[start.index : end.index]` work?

Comment: Same error with data.loc[...]

Comment: OK how about `data.loc[start.index[0] : end.index[0]]`?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to access the scalar value inside the single row `Series` and pass this to `loc` to slice the df:

```
data.loc[start.index[0] : end.index[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using references to `Series` in your slicing.  Instead try:

```
series = data[start.index[0] : end.index[0]]
```

I think your `start` and `end` are single period series.